# Confused about the use of "on" in "missed opportunity on sth" and "launched a campaign on sth"

Tags: clauses

Is it normal (in American English) to say:
1. Collected student body feedback and identified missed opportunity on the lack of campus safety instructions.
2. Launched a successful campus-wide campaign on raising student safety awareness and precautions among 7,000 students.

Comment: It's a dictionary definition of "on." 3. having (the thing mentioned) as a topic; about.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question: Yes, using on in those situations is perfectly normal and acceptable in American English. It is a textbook definition of the preposition "on":

"... noting the goal to which some action is or has been directed; "about, concerning, regarding; in a position to cover;"" https://www.etymonline.com/word/on

The long answer (which is actually kind of short) as to why it is this way: It just is.